# Understanding NuGet Package dependecies from Nuget.org

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-6.0, nuget-package

I am a bit confused as how to interpret the *dependencies* list available on nuget.org and in the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio...

Sometimes, the list contains frameworks and a sub-list of dependencies per framework. Sometimes it does not contain the framework I have targeted for a particular project at all, how do I interpret this?

For example, this package's latest stable version is `7.0.5`. I have chosen to only update my version to `6.0.16` because that is the latest version which mentions `net6` as a dependency.
[image]

Versions 7 and above only mention `net7.0` with dependencies, hence why I only dare to update to latest 6.X.X. Is my interpretation correct? Should I only update to the latest version mentioning net6 in the dependecy list (when my project targets net6), or can I update to the 7.X.X versions anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A package author can choose what target framework monikers (TFMs) to support; this can be diverse or ultra-specific. In this case (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore), they have gone "specific", with the v6 versions of the library only targeting net6, v7 versions of the library only targeting net7, etc; so yes, your interpretation is correct and 6.0.16 looks to be the latest you can use with .net 6; if you attempt to install a v7 version of the lib, it *should* fail to install the package and/or build, because something targeting net7 *could* be using APIs that simply do not exist in net6, giving runtime failures - the package system attempts to protect you from that.

Now, it *might* be that the package *could* work on net6, but targeting multiple frameworks is *effort* that requires testing, and may involve code changes (in particular `#if` sections or similar, to use better approaches when available, or fallback approaches when not). It is not unreasonable for authors to say, more simply:

> The vOlder version is what it is - we *may* supply out-of-band updates for security fixes or bugs that cross a certain threshold, and you can keep using vOlder with your netOlder applications, but if you want newer features you'll need to use vNewer on netNewer.

This is on a per-package basis, and many packages are far more diverse in what they target, either by having a wide range of TFMs, or by having wide-reaching targets such as netstandard2.0 (which *in theory* works on a wide range of platforms, by virtue of only consuming a common intersection of APIs).

Comment: Okay, thanks for your detailed reply Marc! I find it safest to avoid upgrading packages to versions that don't explicitly list net6 or netstandard then. I am just curious as to why the VS Nuget Package manager suggest these upgrades at all? I feel like it could check the projects target framework and from there, at least, suggest only the latest stable confirmed compatible version.

Comment: @Matheos you're not wrong